# Is there a JMX widget/component/plugin to allow execution of MBeans in webapp UI?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jmx, mbeans

Good afternoon,

I am currently building a webapp using Java, JSF, Primefaces and I'd like admin-users to run certain batch-jobs. At first I thought about simply creating a simple UI to do this myself, but I then I realized that it would be better to use some type of plugin/widget that simply just takes all available MBeans and displays it for the user in some way. This way I wouldn't have to constantly create more UI-elements whenever a new job is created. I used Apache Sirona before to do this, but I want to limit access of these functions to certain users instead.

So my question is: Are there any plugins/tools like this available?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Jolokia.  It wraps all your JMX beans in REST API.

https://jolokia.org/

Then it should be trivial to use from your JSF pages or any other UI component.  We do this for one of our projects.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! I'll accept your answer.